# DDD: entity's collection and repositories

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Suppose I have

```
public class Product: Entity
{
   public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I want to find an item with max something... I can add the method `Product.GetMaxItemSmth()` and do it with Linq (`from i in Items select i.smth).Max()`) or with a manual loop or whatever. Now, the problem is that this will load the full collection into memory.

The correct solution will be to do a specific DB query, but domain entities do not have access to repositories, right? So either I do

```
productRepository.GetMaxItemSmth(product)
```

(which is ugly, no?), or even if entities have access to repositories, I use `IProductRepository` from entity

```
product.GetMaxItemSmth() { return Service.GetRepository<IProductRepository>().GetMaxItemSmth(); }
```

which is also ugly and is a duplication of code. I can even go fancy and do an extension

```
public static IList<Item> GetMaxItemSmth(this Product product)
{
   return Service.GetRepository<IProductRepository>().GetMaxItemSmth();
}
```

which is better only because it doesn't really clutter the entity with repository... but still does method duplication.

Now, this is the problem of whether to use `product.GetMaxItemSmth()` or `productRepository.GetMaxItemSmth(product)`... again. Did I miss something in DDD? What is the correct way here? Just use `productRepository.GetMaxItemSmth(product)`? Is this what everyone uses and are happy with?

I just don't feel it is right... if I can't access a product's `Items` from the product itself, why do I need this collection in `Product` at all??? And then, can `Product` do anything useful if it can't use specific queries and access its collections without performance hits?

Of course, I can use a less efficient way and never mind, and when it's slow I'll inject repository calls into entities as an optimization... but even this doesn't sound right, does it?

One thing to mention, maybe it's not quite DDD... but I need IList in Product in order to get my DB schema generated with Fluent NHibernate. Feel free to answer in pure DDD context, though.

UPDATE: a very interesting option is described here: http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/12/03/custom-collections-with-nhibernate-part-i-the-basics.aspx, not only to deal with DB-related collection queries, but also can help with collection access control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having an `Items` collection *and* having `GetXXX()` methods are both correct.

To be pure, your Entities shouldn't have direct access to Repositories.  However, they *can* have an indirect reference via a **Query Specification**.  Check out page 229 of Eric Evans' book.  Something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public IList<Item> Items {get;}

    public int GetMaxItemSmth()
    {
        return new ProductItemQuerySpecifications().GetMaxSomething(this);
    }
}

public class ProductItemQuerySpecifications()
{
   public int GetMaxSomething(product)
   {
      var respository = MyContainer.Resolve<IProductRespository>();
      return respository.GetMaxSomething(product);
   }
}
```

How you get a reference to the Repository is your choice (DI, Service Locator, etc). Whilst this removes the direct reference between Entity and Respository, it doesn't reduce the LoC.

Generally, I'd only introduce it early if I knew that the number of `GetXXX()` methods will cause problems in the future. Otherwise, I'd leave it for a future refactoring exercise.

Comment: I accept it because it complies with how I feel it's easier to deal with the problem, this doesn't mean it's the right answer (are there any, after all? ;-).

Comment: What problems does this approach avoid, that allowing the entity to access the repository directly would not avoid?

Comment: IMO creating indirect reference to repo is much worse than direct.

Answer (score 6):

I believe in terms of DDD, whenever you are having problems like this, **you should first ask yourself if your entity was designed properly**.

If you say that Product has a list of Items. You are saying that Items is a part of the Product aggregate. That means that, if you perform data changes on the Product, you are changing the items too. In this case, your Product and it's items are required to be transactionally consistent. That means that changes to one or another should always cascade over the entire Product aggregate, and the change should be ATOMIC. Meaning that, if you changed the Product's name and the name of one of it's Items and if the database commit of the Item's name works, but fails on the Product's name, the Item's name should be rolled back.

This is the fact that **Aggregates should represent consistency boundaries, not compositional convenience.**

If it does not make sense in your domain to require changes on Items and changes on the Product to be transactionally consistent, then Product should not hold a reference to the Items.

**You are still allowed to model the relationship between Product and items**, you just shouldn't have a direct reference. Instead, you want to have an indirect reference, that is, Product will have a list of Item Ids.

The choice between having a direct reference and an indirect reference should be based first on the question of transactional consistency. Once you have answered that, if it seemed that you needed the transactional consistency, you must then further ask if it could lead to scalability and performance issues.

If you have too many items for too many products, this could scale and perform badly. In that case, you should consider eventual consistency. This is when you still only have an indirect reference from Product to items, but with some other mechanism, you guarantee that at some future point in time (hopefully as soon as possible), the Product and the Items will be in a consistent state. The example would be that, as Items balances are changed, the Products total balance increases, while each item is being one by one altered, the Product might not exactly have the right Total Balance, but as soon as all items will have finished changing, the Product will update itself to reflect the new Total Balance and thus return to a consistent state.

That last choice is harder to make, you have to determine if it is acceptable to have eventual consistency in order to avoid the scalability and performance problems, or if the cost is too high and you'd rather have transactional consistency and live with the scalability and performance issues.

**Now, once you have indirect references to Items, how do you perform GetMaxItemSmth()?**

In this case, I believe the best way is to use the double dispatch pattern. You create an ItemProcessor class:

```
public class ItemProcessor
{
    private readonly IItemRepository _itemRepo;
    public ItemProcessor(IItemRepository itemRepo)
    {
        _itemRepo = itemRepo;
    }

    public Item GetMaxItemSmth(Product product)
    {
        // Here you are free to implement the logic as performant as possible, or as slowly
        // as you want.

        // Slow version
        //Item maxItem = _itemRepo.GetById(product.Items[0]);
        //for(int i = 1; i < product.Items.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    Item item = _itemRepo.GetById(product.Items[i]);
        //    if(item > maxItem) maxItem = item;
        //}

        //Fast version
        Item maxItem = _itemRepo.GetMaxItemSmth();

        return maxItem;
    }
}
```

And it's corresponding interface:

```
public interface IItemProcessor
{
    Item GetMaxItemSmth(Product product);
}
```

Which will be responsible for performing the logic you need that involves working with both your Product data and other related entities data. Or this could host any kind of complicated logic that spans multiple entities and don't quite fit in on any one entity per say, because of how it requires data that span multiple entities.

Than, on your Product entity you add:

```
public class Product
{
    private List<string> _items; // indirect reference to the Items Product is associated with
    public List<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public Product(List<string> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public Item GetMaxItemSmth(IItemProcessor itemProcessor)
    {
        return itemProcessor.GetMaxItemSmth(this);
    }
}
```

*NOTE:
If you only need to query the Max items and get a value back, not an Entity, you should bypass this method altogether. Create an IFinder that has a GetMaxItemSmth that returns your specialised read model. It's ok to have a separate model only for querying, and a set of Finder classes that perform specialized queries to retrieve such specialized read model. As you must remember, Aggregates only exist for the purpose of data change. Repositories only work on Aggregates. Therefore, if no data change, no need for either Aggregates or Repositories.*

Comment: So you want to say that there should be no query methods in Repository? no find() or find_all() methods??

Comment: @Andrew There should be query methods, but they should only exist for the purpose of data modification. If you have a view that displays items of a certain weight, color and for a specific date range, this should not be a Find method on the Repository. If from that view, you click on an item and select Edit, and there you can change the item, at that new edit view, you should query the Repository using the Item's ID for the Aggregate that let's you modify the item.

Comment: @Andrew Basically, you should be doing Repo.FindSomething(). For all these things, modify them. Finally, Repo.UpdateTheseThings(). If you are finding stuff, but not following it up with an edit and save back to the repo, then it's not adequate. You want a Read model and a different system for those, which might be using different entities too.

Comment: ok so you just split data operations into 'Read-Only' and 'Read-Modify-Save'. I understand that. So which patterns (objects) you use for 'Read-Only' cases? Do you have some sources with more info about this? Some examples? What is that 'Read model' you mention? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer, I am just starting to get a grasp on DDD. or at least believe doing it :) )

I will second Mark on this one and emphasize 2 point that took me some times to realize.

- Think about your object in term of aggregates, which lead to

  > The point is that either you load the children together with the parent or you load them separately

The difficult part is to think about the aggregate for your problem at hand and not to focus the DB structure supporting it.
An example that emphasizes this point i customer.Orders. Do you really need *all* the orders of your customer for adding a new order? usually not. what if she has 1 millin of them?
You might need something like OutstandingAmount or AmountBuyedLastMonth in order to fulfill some scenarios like "AcceptNewOrder" or ApplyCustomerCareProgram.

- Is the product the real aggregate root for your sceanrio?

  > What if Product is not an Aggregate Root?

i.e. are you going to manipulate the item or the product?
If it is the product, do you need the ItemWithMaxSomething or do you need MaxSomethingOfItemsInProduct?

- Another myth: PI means You don't need to think about the DB

Given that you really need the item with maxSomething in your scenario, then you need to know what it means in terms of database operation in order to choose the right implementation, either through a service or a property.
For example if a product has a huge number of items, a solution might be to have the ID of the Item recorded with the product in the db instead of iterating over the all list.

*The difficult part for me in DDD is to define the right aggregates. I feel more and more that if I need to rely on lazy loading then I might have overseen some context boundary.*

hope this helps :)

Comment: I see the point of your and Mark's answers. With old-fashioned manual repository (not NHibernate) I wouldn't probably even think about Items - unless I needed them. But with Items helping me to generate DB schema... Anyway, now I do get this feeling that NHibernate makes it too easy to violate good design ;-) I think the answer is "yes, use repository" but I'm still not sure why having Order Items separately from Order makes good domain classes... after all it's not natural. Items are very nice for adding/deleting/etc, except filtering.

Comment: And I can just pass Product to page and have items displayed... while with separate repository I'll need to grab them from another repository, pack into separate DTO object for the view... Now I see why Services are so important for pure DDD - these extra work has to be performed somewhere ;-)))

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a difficult question that has no hard and fast answer.

A key to one answer is to analyze Aggregates and Associations as discussed in [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). The point is that *either* you load the children together with the parent *or* you load them separately.

When you load them together with the parent (Product in your example), the parent controls *all* access to the children, including retrieval and write operations. A corrolary to this is that there must be no repository for the children - data access is managed by the parent's repository.

So to answer one of your questions: "why do I need this collection in Product at all?" Maybe you don't, but if you do, that would mean that Items would *always* be loaded when you load a Product. You could implement a Max method that would simply find the Max by looking over all Items in the list. That may not be the most performant implementation, but that would be the way to do it if Product was an Aggregate Root.

What if Product is *not* an Aggregate Root? Well, the first thing to do is to remove the Items property from Product. You will then need some sort of Service that can retrieve the Items associated with the Product. Such a Service could also have a GetMaxItemSmth method.

Something like this:

```
public class ProductService
{
    private readonly IItemRepository itemRepository;

    public ProductService (IItemRepository itemRepository)
    {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetMaxItemSmth(Product product)
    {
        var max = this.itemRepository.GetMaxItemSmth(product);
        // Do something interesting here
        return max;
    }
}
```

That is pretty close to your extension method, but with the notable difference that the repository should be an instance injected into the Service. Static stuff is never good for modeling purposes.

As it stands here, the ProductService is a pretty thin wrapper around the Repository itself, so it may be redundant. Often, however, it turns out to be a good place to add other interesting behavior, as I have tried to hint at with my code comment.

Comment: Basically you tell that if I need some operation on subitems (which is 90% case) then I can't have the collection inside entity... and instead of doing lazy load and all funny stuff with NHibernate (i.e. have collection in entity) I need to add manual methods to repositories for GetItemsByProduct(product), etc? Doesn't sound right. I'll better do both product.Items and productRepository.GetMaxItemSmth(product)... at least less manual work and no problems except different Intellisense entry point ;-)

Comment: Yes, lazy or implicit loading is at odds with DDD which states that everything should be explicitly modeled. I'm not saying that it is the best way, or the only way to do things - I'm just saying that this is the DDD way. Implicitly loading navigation properties is not. It's not wrong to do that, it's just a different philosophy - but you asked about it in a DDD context :)

Comment: @queen3 I think this guy is right. In DDD, you're aggregates should be modeled around transactional consistency boundaries and not compositional convenience. It means that either your Product must be changed transactionally with all of it's items. Meaning you would load all items as part of the object in eager loading. Or your Product does not hold a reference to the Items, but instead, an indirect reference to their Ids. In which case, I am not sure yet how you traverse that indirect reference to Item IDS from the Product, which you also ask in your question, I can't answer that part though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can solve this problem is to track it all in the aggregate root.  If Product and Item are both part of the same aggregate, with Product being the root, then all access to the Items is controlled via Product.  So in your AddItem method, compare the new Item to the current max item and replace it if need be.  Maintain it where it's needed within Product so you don't have to run the SQL query at all.  This is one reason why defining aggregates promotes encapsulation.

Comment: A nice method, however, when Product is loaded by NH which do not call my AddItem()... I do not get max. And it's not always good to calculate Max() all the time just in case - maybe nobody needs it. If I need 10 such calculations should I perform all of them each time Item is added/removed...

Comment: Why do you need to recalculate Max when it's loaded from NHibernate?  Do you have other systems that use the same DB and will change data without going through your app?  I'm also assuming that a simple comparison of a new item to the current Max item is trivial in cost, if you feel otherwise, then discount this approach.

Comment: Hm, now I see the point better. This is also a nice solution, though I think it's better to apply it when performance is bad (as with any optimization), especially comparing to the cost of additional field in DB just for the purpose (imagine several calculations). Still an acceptable solution in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that NHibernate is a *mapper* between the database and your objects.  Your issue appears to me that your object model is not a viable relational model, and that's ok, but you need to embrace that.

Why not map another collection to your Product entity that uses the power of your relational model to load in an efficient manner.  Am I right in assuming that the logic to select this special collection is not rocket science and could easily be implemented in filtered NHibernate mapped collection?

I know my answer has been vague, but I only understand your question in general terms.  My point is that you *will* have problems if you treat your relational database in an object oriented manner.  Tools like NHibernate exist to bridge the gap between them, not to treat them in the same way.  Feel free to ask me to clarify any points I didn't make clear.

Comment: That's true, it is not clear... it seems like you concentrate on how to load the collection which I have no problem with. But, however I load the collection, in order to calculate MAX() I'll need to send ALL its data over the wire to my C# app. I need a separate method that will perform the query on DB and send me the result in ANY case. The question is can my entities use this method if needed (via DI)... and the best answer I see for now is "it depends".

Comment: Instead of having a separate method to query the DB and worrying about whether or not to inject a repository, have a separate *property* and use a custom NHibernate mapping to load the value when the entity is loaded.  Use the power of the relational model to do what it is good at instead of trying to shoehorn the same logic into your OO model.

Comment: I don't understand, how do I load result of an aggregate SQL query (SELECT MAX()) into a property and how do I make this query to execute only when property is accessed instead of when entity is loaded? And one thing I totally missed... how do I calculate max for a "new Product()" - which hasn't been stored in DB yet? Do I provide 2 implementations of GetMax() - one for memory object and another for already persisted? Smth like "if (Id == 0) return this.Max() else return injectedRepository.Max()"...

Comment: Yes, you can load aggregate data into a property using NHibernate.  If you need to track changes to items and new products, you can do that, Product is your aggregate root after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do that with NHibernate 5 directly without specific code !
It won't load the whole collection into memory.

See https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt

```
Build 5.0.0
=============================

** Highlights
...
    * Entities collections can be queried with .AsQueryable() Linq extension without being fully loaded.
...
```