# Querying for entities in an aggregate other than the root

Tags: design-patterns, repository, domain-driven-design

In the context of DDD, it's always said that a Repository must only query for aggregate roots. Aggregate roots then give access to other entities in the aggregate. However, how are queries to entities within the aggregate modeled?

Suppose the case of an Orders aggregate. Order is the root and have a list of detail Lines, which make reference to a Product (which is the root to another aggregate) and have other attributes like quantity

Now, suppose I need to list or order lines that make reference to an specific product, to generate a report that is used by diverse services, like calculate the average number of items requested by order for a product.

Searching for every Oder, then listing all Lines and selecting the one I'm interested in, sounds impractical. A getLinesByProduct() at the Orders repository sounds more convenient, but will expose Lines out of the Aggregate.

How can I model this query?

Maybe the problem is that I'm querying my Command model and I should have a (denormalized) Query model on which details lines are entities with all the needed information?

Comment: Update:I have found a closely related question ["DDD: entity's collection and repositories"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356430/ddd-entitys-collection-and-repositories). The conclusion in that case was that the entities should be in its own aggregate. Thar reinforces my intuituion that in my case, the same solution applies.

Comment: Are the reports part of the core application or a separate application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe the problem is that I'm querying my Command model and I should
>   have a (denormalized) Query model on which details lines are entities
>   with all the needed information?

This is exactly right. DDD isn't meant to address query concerns and often retorts with friction due to its various constraints and the constraints imposed by an ORM. Queries and especially reporting should be handled separately. You may use the [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) to support queries that are part of the core application, or use a completely separate reporting system, which operates based on replicated data.